# Custom QSettings functions not called

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I have the following piece of code, that is supposed to provide the XML functionality for `Qsettings` eventually:

```
/**
 * @brief   Custom XML format reading function.
 * @param   device: ie. the read file.
 * @param   map: key + value to read
 * @return  non zero on succesfull read.
 */
static bool readXmlFile(QIODevice& device,  QSettings::SettingsMap& map)
{
    qDebug() << __func__ << " called";
    (void)device;
    (void)map;
    return false;
}

/**
 * @brief   Custom XML format writing function.
 * @param   device: ie. the written file.
 * @param   map: key + value to read
 * @return  non zero on succesfull write.
 */
static bool writeXmlFile(QIODevice& device, const QSettings::SettingsMap& map)
{
    qDebug() << __func__ << " called";
    (void)device;
    (void)map;
    return false;
}

/**
 * @brief   Initializes the settings object.
 * @param   path: Full path to the file. If it doesnt exist, it is created.
 * @param   parent: the parent object.
 */
Cxmlsettings::Cxmlsettings(const QString& path, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QFileInfo fi(path);
    if (!fi.exists() || !fi.isFile())
    {
        // config file doesnt exist, create it.
        QFile cFile(path);
        if (!cFile.open(QIODevice::NewOnly))
        {
            qCritical() << "Failed to create " << path << " file";
            return;
        }

        cFile.close();
    }

    const QSettings::Format xmlformat =
            QSettings::registerFormat("xml", &readXmlFile, &writeXmlFile);

    m_settings.setPath(xmlformat, QSettings::UserScope, path);
    m_settings.setValue("abc", 10);
    volatile const int test = m_settings.value("abc").toInt();
}
```

My problem is that after I set the path for the `m_settings` variable, and run the write and read functions, my custom functions `readXmlFile` and `writeXmlFile` are not being called. The file under `path` always exists, because it is created if it doesnt exist prior to calling the `setValue`.

Comment: But maybe it should be `QSettings::registerFormat("xml", readXmlFile, writeXmlFile);` instead? Note how I pass the read/write functions to the function.

Comment: Checked it and its still not the case, they are not called.

Comment: Did you check the output of `registerFormat` against `QSettings::InvalidFormat` value?

Comment: Yes, its `QSettings::Customformat1`

Comment: One more point. Maybe you must construct your `QSettings` object with the new format. I think that `setPath` just sets the path, where the settings should be stored, but not defines how they will be stored. Just an idea.

Comment: Note that [`QSettings::setPath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#setPath) is a static member of `QSettings`.  I suspect that only `QSettings` instances created *after* calling it will be affected.  Just a guess though.

Comment: Corrent, you are right. Creating a new instance with my custom format makes the write function work Read was not called due to the fact that the file is 0 bytes probably. Thanks.